# How many arrangements of the word NUMBER exist if the N is somewhere on the right of U?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is the photo of the question.
I have tried many different by placing U in different spots but it doesn't give me the right answer. I keep getting 192 when the answer is actually 360. It would help a lot if someone would answer this question for me.

Comment: Use a symmetry argument against the $(6!)$ arrangements.  Intuitively, the number of arrangements with $N$ before $U$ should be the same as the number of arrangements with $N$ after $U$.

Comment: You have six positions to fill.  In how many ways can you place the M, B, E, and R in those six positions?  Once you have done so, there is only way to place the N and U in the remaining two positions so that the N is somewhere to the right of the U.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one approach:

There are $6! = 720$ ways to arrange the 6 letters of NUMBER without restriction.

You can pair all of those up into one arrangement where N comes before U, and one where U comes before N, but the rest of the letters are in the same place.

Therefore, the number of arrangements with U before N is half of the total number of arrangements, which is $\frac{720}{2} = 360$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be mapped onto another anagram puzzle, where there are repeated letters: How many anagrams are there of *BOOMER*?

This is the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $\binom{6}{2,1,1,1,1} = \frac{6!}{2!1!1!1!1!} = \frac{720}{2} = 360$

Then we map back to the original requirement by changing the lefthand *O* to *U* and the righthand *O* to *N*.